# Plugging one's ears

Tags: expressions

can somebody share with me their knowledge?

How to call in the best way the action of puting fingers in one's ears in order not to hear sth or sb.

I know there is "to plug one's ears" but I also have seen a sentence like this

" I was cupping my hands over my ears" which sounds a bit artificial to me.

Maybe, there is yet different way of saying this ?

Comment: ***Stop one's ears:*** http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stop-one%27s-ears

Comment: Be clear:  Are you speaking of a motion to protect the person from loud noises, or a motion used by the person to indicate that he does not wish to hear what's being said?

Comment: Motion used by the person to indicate that he does not wish to hear what's being said.

Comment: ***Cupping*** your ears looks [like this](http://www.earglasses.com/images/Beautysmall.jpg). It means using your hand to make a bigger trumpet for the ear, so you can hear ***better*** (not *shut sound **out***).

Answer (score 5):

A sudden, extremely loud noise, will usually elicit the reflex of raising the entire hand(s) to ***cover one's ears***. After this initial reflex - if the noise continues - the fingers may be used more precisely to fill the various gaps.

The action of inserting the fingers directly into the ear canal requires a slower, more calculated movement - due to the risk of missing the target. It is usually done for emphasis, for example: to insult someone - and is usually referred to as **"sticking one's fingers in one's ears."**

Answer (score 0):

If you want the focus on "in order not to hear sth or sb" (like ignoring), not necessarily the physical action of it, I think, you can use "**bury one's head in sand,** " or **"turn deaf ear."**

Found them on Dictionary.com Thesaurus. (link: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/bury%20one's%20head%20in%20sand)